# What is an Atom Splitting Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>

---

If a word satisfies a certain property, it is called an Atom Splitting Word™. Use the example word lists below to find the rule. Each word can be tested for whether it is an Atom Splitting Word™ without depending on other words in these lists.

What is the property that makes a word an Atom Splitting Word™ ?

And why is it called an Atom Splitting Word™ ?

Note that font and capitalization do not matter.

| Atom Splitting Words™ | Not Atom Splitting Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABERRATION | MUTANT |
| BURLAP | COTTON |
| CARBOXYL | CARBOXYLIC |
| ELECTRON | NEUTRINO |
| FORM | FORMAL |
| FUNCTIONAL | FUNCTION |
| ILLUSTRATE | DEMONSTRATE |
| LEVITATION | FLIGHT |
| MICROSCOPE | ATOMIC |
| MORALIST | PHILOSOPHERS |
| NOBLEWOMAN | ARISTOCRAT |
| PERFORMING | PERFUNCTORY |
| PHYLUM | TAXONOMY |
| ROYALE | KINGDOM |
| SAILOR | SUBMARINE |
| STRIFE | SUFFERING |
| TEMPORAL | VARYING |
| UMPIRE | REFEREE |
| UNDOCUMENTED | UNKNOWN |
| WERE | WAS |
| YEARBOOK | PHOTOGRAPH |
| ZINC | GOLD |

CSV version:

```
Atom Splitting Words™,Not Atom Splitting Words™
ABERRATION,MUTANT
BURLAP,COTTON
CARBOXYL,CARBOXYLIC
ELECTRON,NEUTRINO
FORM,FORMAL
FUNCTIONAL,FUNCTION
ILLUSTRATE,DEMONSTRATE
LEVITATION,FLIGHT
MICROSCOPE,ATOMIC
MORALIST,PHILOSOPHERS
NOBLEWOMAN,ARISTOCRAT
PERFORMING,PERFUNCTORY
PHYLUM,TAXONOMY
ROYALE,KINGDOM
SAILOR,SUBMARINE
STRIFE,SUFFERING
TEMPORAL,VARYING
UMPIRE,REFEREE
UNDOCUMENTED,UNKNOWN
WERE,WAS
YEARBOOK,PHOTOGRAPH
ZINC,GOLD
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have the answer. Credit to @Riley in the comments for greatly simplifying my solution:

> An Atom Splitting Word™ has the same number of letters in the first half of the alphabet as in the second half.
>
>  For example, take ABERRATION. From left to right, there are 5 letters A, B, E, A, and I in the first half of the alphabet (A-M). There are also 5 letters R, R, T, O and N in the second half of the alphabet (N-Z).

Why the name "Atom Splitting" applies:

> When you split the alphabet, the first half consists of the letters "**A**to**M**".

Output of analysis for all provided Atom Splitting Word™s:

> Word: ABERRATION
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: BURLAP
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: CARBOXYL
>  Number letters in range A-M: 4
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 4
>
>  Word: ELECTRON
>  Number letters in range A-M: 4
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 4
>
>  Word: FORM
>  Number letters in range A-M: 2
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 2
>
>  Word: FUNCTIONAL
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: ILLUSTRATE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: LEVITATION
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: MICROSCOPE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: MORALIST
>  Number letters in range A-M: 4
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 4
>
>  Word: NOBLEWOMAN
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: PERFORMING
>  Number letters in range A-M: 5
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 5
>
>  Word: PHYLUM
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: ROYALE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: SAILOR
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: STRIFE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: TEMPORAL
>  Number letters in range A-M: 4
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 4
>
>  Word: UMPIRE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 3
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 3
>
>  Word: UNDOCUMENTED
>  Number letters in range A-M: 6
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 6
>
>  Word: WERE
>  Number letters in range A-M: 2
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 2
>
>  Word: YEARBOOK
>  Number letters in range A-M: 4
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 4
>
>  Word: ZINC
>  Number letters in range A-M: 2
>  Number of letters in range N-Z: 2

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to this much simpler explanation? Rot13(Gur jbeq unf gur fnzr ahzore bs yrggref va N-Z nf A-M.) So there's no need to rot13(Fcyvg gur jbeq va unys qbja gur zvqqyr)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I can't believe that went over my head. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Good work!  Can you also include why the name "Atom Splitting" applies?  Hint: it's a pun.

Comment: @MikeQ Sure thing, I just added that. I hope I got the entire pun.

Comment: That's not really a pun. Don't overthink this. Hint: rot13(jung qb lbh pnyy gur svefg unys bs gur nycunorg)?

Comment: @MikeQ Wow... nice one.